# Which keywords trigger the captcha page on pastebin.com?

Tags: pastebin

As the title says, I need some keywords to trigger the captcha page on www.pastebin.com (in order to test [this unofficial api i made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777849/1067003)), I just don't know how to trigger it. I remember I have triggered it in the past, but i don't remember what i was pasting when i did.

I have tried generic stuff like urls (even 4chan /b/ urls), and stuff like `BUY FREE BITCOIN HERE {url}` but that didn't seem to work either.

- I even went to my email spam folder to try some real spam, but real spam like `IM HORNY 19YO LOOKING FOR YOUR CREDIT CARD BLAH BLAH` didn't seem to trigger the filter either.

Anyone knows how to trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

try some external links like https://someweb.xyz

this will trigger for sure from my experience